# XML Path List - Generate only certain nodes

Tags: xml, for-xml-path

I have the following XML input from this webpage.

https://www.bike-king.com/product/specialized-mens-stumpjumper-st-comp-carbon-29-12-speed-344617-1.htm

```
<ol class="breadcrumb seProductBreadcrumb">
<li>
<a href="/" data-value="Home" data-ui="product-breadcrumbs">
<span>Home</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/catalog/bicycling-catalog-39/" data-value="Bicycling Catalog" data-ui="product-breadcrumbs">
<span>Bicycling Catalog</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/product-list/bikes-1000/" data-value="Bikes" data-ui="product-breadcrumbs">
<span>Bikes</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/product-list/bikes-1000/mountain-1006/" data-value="Mountain" data-ui="product-breadcrumbs">
<span>Mountain</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/product-list/bikes-1000/mountain-1006/29-inch-wheel-29ers-1009/" data-value="29-Inch Wheel (29ers)" data-ui="product-breadcrumbs">
<span>29-Inch Wheel (29ers)</span>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/product-list/bikes-1000/mountain-1006/29-inch-wheel-29ers-1009/?rb_br=349" data-value="Specialized" data-ui="product-breadcrumbs">
<span>Specialized</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="hidden-xs active">
<span class="hidden-xs">
Men's Stumpjumper ST Comp Carbon 29 – 12-Speed
</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

My XML path

```
//ol[@class="breadcrumb seProductBreadcrumb"]/li/a
```

generates me the following output:

```
<a href="/" data:value="Home" data:ui="product:breadcrumbs">
<span>Home</span>
</a>
<a href="/catalog/bicycling:catalog:39/" data:value="Bicycling Catalog" data:ui="product:breadcrumbs">
<span>Bicycling Catalog</span>
</a>
<a href="/product:list/bikes:1000/" data:value="Bikes" data:ui="product:breadcrumbs">
<span>Bikes</span>
</a>
<a href="/product:list/bikes:1000/mountain:1006/" data:value="Mountain" data:ui="product:breadcrumbs">
<span>Mountain</span>
</a>
<a href="/product:list/bikes:1000/mountain:1006/29:inch:wheel:29ers:1009/" data:value="29:Inch Wheel (29ers)" data:ui="product:breadcrumbs">
<span>29:Inch Wheel (29ers)</span>
</a>
<a href="/product:list/bikes:1000/mountain:1006/29:inch:wheel:29ers:1009/?rb_br=349" data:value="Specialized" data:ui="product:breadcrumbs">
<span>Specialized</span>
</a>
```

The result is 6 elements. How can I get say only middle 2 or 3 or 4 elements?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "only middle 2 or 3 or 4 elements"? Is there a criterion for selecting those, or is it just random?

Comment: The criteria is varying for me right now. Sometimes I have 6 elements, sometimes a different. As an example, I am open to answer if last 4 elements are picked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last 4 elements in the sample xml in the question, this xpath expression

```
//ol[@class="breadcrumb seProductBreadcrumb"]//li[position() >= (last()-4)]//a
```

Outputs

```
<a data-ui="product-breadcrumbs"
   data-value="Bikes"
   href="/product-list/bikes-1000/">
   <span>Bikes</span>
</a>
<a data-ui="product-breadcrumbs"
   data-value="Mountain"
   href="/product-list/bikes-1000/mountain-1006/">
   <span>Mountain</span>
</a>
<a data-ui="product-breadcrumbs"
   data-value="29-Inch Wheel (29ers)"
   href="/product-list/bikes-1000/mountain-1006/29-inch-wheel-29ers-1009/">
   <span>29-Inch Wheel (29ers)</span>
</a>
<a data-ui="product-breadcrumbs"
   data-value="Specialized"
   href="/product-list/bikes-1000/mountain-1006/29-inch-wheel-29ers-1009/?rb_br=349">
   <span>Specialized</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Am I right to say if I use //li[position() >= (first()+2)]//a    - I should be getting the same result?

Comment: @JeshKundem In this case - yes. But note that there is no such method as `first()`; to get to the same place just use `position()>=3`.

Comment: What if I want the middle two. What the sytnax for having 'AND' between position()==3 && position()==4

Comment: @JeshKundem Almost; the form usually is something like `position()>=x and position()<=y`.